# Changing the background color of a vector app icon

Tags: java, android, vector

I'm trying to create a little assistant on android for fun and I wanted to use the same icon than google assistant but with a dark background but it doesn't work:
[image]
I tried using a layer-list with a shape (a circle or a square) but it doesn't fit entirely the round icon.
I also tried that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/midnightblue"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_assistant"/>
</layer-list>
```

but as you can see on the screenshot I got the same result. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set white color to the launcher icon background. For example in `res/mipmap-anydpi-v26` directory:

**ic_launcher.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

**ic_launcher_round.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

And in `res/drawable` directory:

**ic_launcher_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportHeight="108"
    android:viewportWidth="108">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M0,0h108v108h-108z" />
</vector>
```

After all, we can scale the inside icon to force it contained in circle.

**ic_assistant.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">

    <group
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:translateX="128"
        android:translateY="128">

        <path
            android:fillColor="#4285F4"
            android:pathData="M156.268,167.705m-156.268,0a156.268,156.268 0,1 1,312.536 0a156.268,156.268 0,1 1,-312.536 0" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#34A853"
            android:pathData="M512,182.95c0,17.544 -14.224,31.762 -31.762,31.762s-31.762,-14.218 -31.762,-31.762c0,-17.543 14.224,-31.762 31.762,-31.762S512,165.407 512,182.95z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#EA4335"
            android:pathData="M454.829,260.449c0,35.081 -28.438,63.522 -63.523,63.522c-35.088,0 -63.524,-28.441 -63.524,-63.522c0,-35.083 28.437,-63.524 63.524,-63.524C426.392,196.925 454.829,225.367 454.829,260.449z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FBBC05"
            android:pathData="M467.533,424.339c0,42.1 -34.124,76.225 -76.228,76.225c-42.104,0 -76.229,-34.125 -76.229,-76.225c0,-42.098 34.124,-76.227 76.229,-76.227C433.409,348.112 467.533,382.241 467.533,424.339z" />

    </group>

</vector>
```

Comment: Here is what I did for ic_launcher_round.xml: https://hastebin.com/uxelinejoc.xml but I don't get exactly what I wanted: https://zupimages.net/up/18/43/cp1f.png

Comment: Is it possible to show me the `ic_assistant` code if it is vector drawable?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can change the scale and translation in the group tag, if you want. Initially I set its scale 0.5.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to exactly contain a square icon in a circle, you should scale it by about 0.7 (sqrt(2) / 2)